# excel batch load with specific sheet

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

Im trying to batch load several xlsx files to a single dataframe. So far i have this piece of code which works great.

```
file.list <- list.files(path = "base-files/", pattern='*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
test1 <- sapply(file.list, read_xlsx, simplify=FALSE) %>%  bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

My issue is related with the number of sheets each xlsx file has. I'm specifically looking to load only sheet # 2 from each file.
Is there any way i could add a *sheet* flag into the *sapply* function?

EDIT:
After running your recommended code, i get some errors. I guess i need to install perl?

```
file.list <- list.files(path = "base-files/", pattern='*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
bind_rows(.id = "id")
test1 = lapply(file.list, function(x) {
                                        sheet_no <- if(sheetCount(x) == 1) 1 else 2
                                        read_xlsx(x, sheet = sheet_no)
                                       }) %>%   bind_rows(.id = 'id')



Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
```

EDIT
Just installed perl for windows
https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `sheet` number

```
sapply(file.list, read_xlsx, sheet = 2, simplify=FALSE) %>%  
       bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

According to `?read_xlsx`

> sheet - Sheet to read. Either a string (the name of a sheet), or an integer (the position of the sheet). Ignored if the sheet is specified via range. If neither argument specifies the sheet, defaults to the first sheet.

---

There is a `sheetCount` function from `gdata`

```
library(gdata)
lapply(file.list, function(x) {
          sheet_no <- if(sheetCount(x) == 1) 1 else 2
          read_xlsx(x, sheet = sheet_no)
    }) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'id')
```

Comment: thanks so much. i didnt know i could use FN flags inside *lapply*.   
one follow up question if I may: excel files have either 1 or 2 sheets. in the case of the 2-sheet files, i need sheet #2. can you advise any approach for this?

Comment: @AndresMora Is it because of the path issue

Comment: @AndresMora I am using Mac, so i cannot test it